# Why does my simple python list get reset to None in a for loop?

Tags: python

I was encountering a bug in a large program that I have managed to isolate to a simpler problem. I am trying to append a list

```
 kk=0
 flist=[]
 for key in range(5):
     if kk==0:
           flist=['w']
     else:
           print "flist*x*", flist
           flist=flist.append('s')
     kk=kk+1
```

In other words, in the first iteration when kk =0, the list should have been initialized and then subsequently appended. However, I get the error:

```
   flist=flist.append('s')
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

I am using python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of `list.append` is `None`.  Python adds the element directly to the list object it is called upon.  You just need to call the function not assign to its return value:

```
flist.append('s')
```